# can i show or hide in same class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs, each one containing a date picker and a button. I would like to show / hide a *single* date picker by clicking on its respective `Reschedule` button. However, in my current solution *all* date pickers are toggled when I click on the button.

I've written this script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".datepicker_reschedule").hide();
        $(".panel-heading").on('click','.reschedule',function(){
            $(".datepicker_reschedule").fadeToggle("slow", "linear" );
        });
    });
    </script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <button class="btn reschedule">Reschedule</button>
        <button class="btn cancel">Cancel</button>
        <span class="datepicker_reschedule">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Save</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="overflow: auto;">content A</div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <button class="btn btn-info reschedule"    id="" style="width:100px">Reschedule</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel"     style="width:100px">Cancel</button>
        <span class="datepicker_reschedule">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Save</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="overflow: auto;">content B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution?

Comment: all textbox appears when I click a button,
I want only one who appeared

Comment: Why don't you use two different ids for both and handle them by ids?

Comment: there are many who would I show but here only two,
because I use the forloop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to find the `relation` between the button to the element you want to toggle. In your case they both are `children` of the same `panel-heading` element.

Therefore, simply changing the element that should be toggled like that:

```
$(this).parent().find(".datepicker_reschedule").fadeToggle("slow", "linear" );
```

- `$(this)` - relates to the clicked button
- `parent()` - the parent of that button
- `find(".datapicker..")` - find the desired element.

Will do the job.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7r3cp84/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet! 
I refer to the element being clicked and I have added the [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent) and the [find()](http://api.jquery.com/parent) functions to your code.
Now it works perfectly!

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".datepicker_reschedule").hide();
        $(".reschedule").on('click',function(e){
            $(this).parent().find(".datepicker_reschedule").fadeToggle("slow", "linear" );
        });
    });
    </script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <button class="btn reschedule">Reschedule</button>
        <button class="btn cancel">Cancel</button>
        <span class="datepicker_reschedule">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Save</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="overflow: auto;">content A</div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <button class="btn btn-info reschedule"    id="" style="width:100px">Reschedule</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel"     style="width:100px">Cancel</button>
        <span class="datepicker_reschedule">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Save</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="overflow: auto;">content B</div>
</div>
```